# XSLT 2 - convert single characters to processing-instruction

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, invisible-xml

I have a text node that contains 7-bit ASCII text as well as higher unicode characters (eg x2011, xF0B7, x25CF ...)

I need to be able to (efficiently) convert these single high-unicode characters into processing-instructions

e.g.

```
&#x2011;  ->   <processing-instruction name="xxx">character output="hyphen"</pro...>
&#xF0B7;  ->   <processing-instruction name="xxx">character output="page"</pro...>
```

I've tried using `xsl:tokenize` which does split the text before/after the first token delimiter (e.g. x2011) but I end up with a variable containing `'text...<processing-instruction>...</processing-instruction'...text'` which trips up the next `xsl:token`.

I managed to get the following approach to work but it looks really inelegant, and I'm sure there's a more efficient/better way to do this but I haven't found anything that works or is any better.

The first character replacement is easy, using `replace()`, as I'm only escaping the `%` (the target software uses the '%' for other things so needs to be escaped in this manner).

And yes, this would work for the x2011-to-< ... >, but the original intention was to convert to processing-instructions directly.

```
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:variable name="SR1">
            <xsl:value-of select="fn:replace(., '%', '\\%')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- unbreakable hyphen -->
        <xsl:variable name="SR2">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$SR1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter">&#x2011;</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="PI"><xsl:text>&lt;?xpp character symbol="bxhyphen" hex="x2011" data="E28091"?&gt;</xsl:text></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- page ref -->
        <xsl:variable name="SR3">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" ><xsl:copy-of select="$SR2"/></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter">&#xF0B7;</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="PI"><xsl:text>&lt;?xpp character symbol="pgref" hex="xF0B7" data="EF82B7"?&gt;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- page ref -->
        <xsl:variable name="SR4">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" ><xsl:copy-of select="$SR3"/></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter">&#x25CF;</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="PI"><xsl:text>&lt;?xpp character symbol="bub" hex="x25CF" data="E2978F"?&gt;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$SR4"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Ideally, I was aiming to have a list of 'pairs', the hex unicode and its matching processing-instruction, but any better solution would be appreciated!

Another feature would be to flag characters that have not been processed, so any characters in the ranges x00-x1F, xFF+ (excluding x2011, x25CF xF0B7).

Comment: If you want to process text to create nodes, then with XSLT 2/3 `xsl:analyze-string` (or in XSLT 3 the `analyze-string` function) are usually the way to go. A processing instruction in the result is normally created with `xsl:processing-instruction`, it is not clear why you use some `xsl:text`.

Comment: Also, what is `xsl:token`? Part of some XSLT extension?

Comment: Oops. Should have been xsl:tokenize ;)

Comment: In an earlier version I did use analyze-string which works for the first character (eg x2011).

I had:
```
<xsl:variable name="SR2">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="$SR1" regex="^(.*)&#x2011;(.*)$">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
        <xsl:processing-instruction> ... </processing-instruction>
     <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:variable>
```
But when I use the same method to define $SR3, calling in $SR2 in the analyze-string/select, it doesn't output the processing-instruction contained in $SR2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the characters you are looking for are known and limited I would list them e.g. `<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&#x2011;&#xF0B7;&#x25CF;"><xsl:matching-substring><xsl:processing-instruction name="xxp" select="mf:map(.)"/></xsl:matching-substring><xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:non-matching-substring></xsl:analyze-string></xsl:template>` where `mf:map` is a function you set up that maps each character to the string you want to output as the data of the pi. In XSLT 3 I would probably store the character to name mapping in an XPath/XSLT map, in XSLT 2 you can use some `xsl:param` or `xsl:variable` e.g. `<xsl:param name="characters-to-name"><map char="&#x2011;">bxhyphen</map>...</xsl:param>` and select into that, if needed, even by setting up a key.

Brand new in the world of XSLT/XPath/XQuery is the recently published invisible XML specification (https://invisiblexml.org/) with various (yet to be polished) implementations; using invisible XML you could define a grammar for your format which the processor then only the fly uses to convert it to XML you can process as normally with XSLT/XPath/XQuery.

So with a grammar of e.g.

```
text: (ascii | hyphen | page | bub)*.
-ascii: ["a"-"z"; "A"-"Z"; "0"-"9"].
hyphen: #2011.
page: #F0B7.
bub: #25CF.
```

the invisible XML processor would convert an input of e.g. `A‑B` into the XML `<text>A<hyphen>‑</hyphen>B</text>` you could process then further with XSLT to create whatever specialized output with, for instance, processing instructions you want.

Comment: I modified the code to read:
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(%|&#x2011;|&#xF0B7;|&#x25CF;)">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
   <xsl:variable name="rg1" select="fn:regex-group(1)"/>
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="xpp" select="$charmap/character[@key=$rg1]"/>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
...
and
 <xsl:variable name="charmap">
  <character key="&#x2011;">bxhyphen</character>
This (very slightly) modified version worked a treat and was way faster than my original code - and much easier to add new character as they make themselves apparent.

Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

A version without `xsl:analyze-string` is the following. It uses a separate file to store the codepoint/string relations.

So, in this example, a file called `codes.xml` contains the mapping(the hex values have to be converted to decimal first - here this is already done):

```
<CharKey>
    <Char cp="8209"  string="hyphen" />
    <Char cp="61623" string="page" />
</CharKey>
```

And the stylesheet (here it is XSLT-3.0, but it works with XSLT-2.0 also with some minor modifications) iterates over the codepoint of the string:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>    
    <xsl:variable name="codes" select="document('codes.xml')/CharKey" />
    <!-- text() node is matched here -->   
    <xsl:template match="/Record/Text">
        <xsl:variable name="cps" select="string-to-codepoints(.)" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$cps">
            <xsl:variable name="curCP" select="$codes/Char[@cp=current()]" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$curCP"><xsl:processing-instruction name="xxx" expand-text="yes">character output="{$curCP/@string}"</xsl:processing-instruction></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="codepoints-to-string(.)" /></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>                
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This could be further simplified, but as an example it should work.
The sample's

```
<Record>
    <Text>Hello&#x2011;&#xF0B7;End</Text>
</Record>
```

output is

```
Hello<?xxx character output="hyphen"?><?xxx character output="page"?>End
```